# Difference between in signed and unsigned char in c

Tags: c, char, signed, unsigned-char

What is the difference between signed and unsigned `char` in C ? When I tried to run the following code without `unsigned` it entered an infinite loop as the range of signed char is up to `127` (Why is it signed by default ?). But when I added `unsigned` (whose range is up to 255) it works fine. What's the reason ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char x;
    x = 0;
    while (x <= 225) {
         printf("%c=%d\n", x, x);
         x = x + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Huh? You just explained the major difference (signed char goes to 127, unsigned to 255) but then you ask what the difference is.

Comment: If plain `char` is signed or unsigned is *implementation defined*. I.e. two different compilers might have it differently.

Comment: @M.M is that the only difference? Are they same in every aspect other than that?

Comment: More significantly, on my windows 10 laptop using gcc, they generate different assembly language instructions. Maybe one is faster/smaller.

Comment: The difference was already explained in the previous question. Shall we provide exact same answers again?

Comment: `char` is not `signed` by default.   It is implementation-defined whether it is `signed` or `unsigned`.    It just so happens, with your implementation, it is a `signed`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no dedicated "character type" in C language. char is an integer type, same (in that regard) as int, short and other integer types.

- They are both integer types.
- They have same size(one btye).

*If you are using numbers as char*

- Signed char, which gives you at least the -127 to 127 range. (-128 to
  127 is common)
- Unsigned char, which gives you at least the 0 to 255 range.

From 3.9.1 Fundamental types

> Plain char, signed char, and unsigned char are three distinct types. A
>   char, a signed char, and an unsigned char occupy the same amount of
>   storage and have the same alignment requirements (3.11); that is, they
>   have the same object representation.

Comment: `char`, `unsigned char`, and `signed char` are known as *character types* however. (These are also integer types)

Answer (score 3):

With the statement

```
x=x+1;
```

there are a few things happening.

First the expression `x + 1` will be evaluated. That will lead to [usual arithmetic conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions) of the value in `x` so it becomes [promoted to an `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions). The (promoted) value will be increased by `1`, and then the result will be assigned back to `x`. And here the problems start.

Because the result of `x + 1` is an `int` it needs to be converted back to a (`signed`) `char`. This is done through [integer conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_conversions) and when converting from a larger signed type (like `int`) to a smaller signed type (like `signed char`) when the value can't fit in the smaller type (like trying to store `128` in a `signed char`) the behavior is *implementation defined*.

What happens in practice is that the value becomes *negative* (the value is increased from `0x7f` to `0x80` which is `-128` in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) (the most common encoding for negative numbers)). This further leads to `x` being less than `225` *forever* and your infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Signed char range is -128 to 127 . Unsigned char range is 0 to 255.
Your while loop will work as expected if the x variable defined as unsigned char.

If you define the variable with signed char, then the variable 'x' laid between -128 to 127. It is always less than 255.

Comment: These are _minimum_ ranges, and may be larger. But, the minimum range for `signed char` is [-127, 127].

Answer (score 1):

- `char` has as size one byte which mean 256 possible values to code.
- `signed` means the value can be negatif or positif,in C standard a variable declared as `signed chard` ranges from `-127` to `127`
- `unsigned` means only positive value and this lead to the fact that variable declared as`unsigned char` range from `0` to `255`

To understand this better let's examine this example `unsigned char x =-1`, the question is what is the vale of x? the answer is x is not -1 in the machine because th compiler will interept x as positive value of type char and so x will be `255` , if we have `unsigned char x = -2` then x egale to 254 and so on. This example so the importance of understanding how the compiler interprets things in background and what result we get during code execution.

Comment: `char` has a size of one byte by definition, but one byte need not be 8 bits. The ranges you state are the _minimum_ ranges guaranteed by the Standard.

Comment: @DavidBowling: actually, the minimum range for the `char` type is 255 values, not 256. Indeed `CHAR_MIN` can be `-127` on non 2's complement systems. We both know this (as you commented on another answer), but this is well beyond the skill level of some of the respondents.

Comment: @chqrlie-- "256 possible values to code"; this actually slipped by me the first time I looked at it. Of course, you are right. I appreciate the note :)

Answer (score 0):

The unsigned char simply means: Use the most significant bit instead of treating it as a bit flag for +/- sign when performing arithmetic operations.

It makes significance if you use char as a number for instance:

typedef char BYTE1;
typedef unsigned char BYTE2;

BYTE1 a;
BYTE2 b;
For variable a, only 7 bits are available and its range is (-127 to 127) = (+/-)2^7 -1. For variable b all 8 bits are available and the range is 0 to 255 (2^8 -1).

If you use char as character, "unsigned" is completely ignored by the compiler just as comments are removed from your program.

Answer (score 0):

Char is a data type which is used in C programming for storing characters like letters and punctuation marks. However, it still remains to be an integer type. This is due to the reason that char type technically stores integers and not characters. It makes use of a numerical code which represents characters by using integers
The transformation of char into int values is done automatically by C. However, it is still dependent on the machine which decides that the result would be negative or not. The upper case A is equivalent to integer value of 65.